# How to get width of Text widget before it has rendered

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a MessageBubble for a messaging app. This is what my MessageBubble looks like when it contains one line:

[image: One line text]

At the moment the MessageBubble will looks like this when it contains more than one line:

[image: Multiline text]

But i want to decide during the build process wether or not two or more lines are displayed in the text so can i add the neccesary padding to the top and the bottom like so (This is a hard-coded examle):

[image]

Is there a way for me to get the number of displayed lines or the width of each line during the build, so I then can decide whether or not to add some padding to the bottom and the top?

This is my code so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BubbleTest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey[350],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: 40.0,
                maxWidth: 250.0,
              ),
              child: Align(
                heightFactor: 1,
                widthFactor: 1,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla lacus libero, molestie vitae dui non, venenatis maximus sem.',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                    textWidthBasis: TextWidthBasis.longestLine,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You cant get these sizes. In widgets you set constraints but final sizes we have after layout is ready. And then we can read them with [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html). From [Google video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUfXWzp0-DU&t=1869s) you can get more information

Comment: You could possibly draw it in Offstage widget, get the size, amend and move it onstage ?

Comment: @Ian I think that could work. But I believe I have come up with a more cost efficient solution. Check my answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

If you're unsure of how you should layout your widget based on the size you can use LayoutBuilder.

```
 LayoutBuilder(
     builder: (context, constraints){
          Padding(
    //based on size if you want to put up your spacing then
                  padding: (constraints.maxHeight < 20)? EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0): EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 15.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla lacus libero, molestie vitae dui non, venenatis maximus sem.',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                    textWidthBasis: TextWidthBasis.longestLine,
                ),
            ),
        }
    )
```

Comment: I am trying to get the width of the Text widget before it is build. The LayoutBuilder is only able to give me the constraints and not the actual size of the displayed widget

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to work around the need for getting the actual width of the Text widget before applying padding to the MessageBubble. Instead i can just add some constant padding to the Alignment widget like so:

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
  child: Align(
    heightFactor: 1,
    widthFactor: 1,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 15.0,
      ),
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18.0,
            color: isFromCurrentUser
                ? Colors.white
                : Colors.black),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

The output:

[image: Working code example]

If i wanted to make the MessageBubble adapt to different text sizes i could make the CircleAvatar's size dependent on the size of the text. If the text was very big the CircleAvatar could grow in size so one line of text would still be centered in the MessageBubble